# Can't fetch data from firebase using Timestamp

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to fetch a value from my collection using the `createdAt` property, which is a timestamp.
This is roughly what my query looks like:

```js
function getDataFromYesterdayToNow (db){
  const now = new Date()
  const yesterday = new Date(now.setDate(now.getDate() - 1))
  yesterday.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)

  const { Timestamp } = firebase.firestore

  return db
    .collection('myData')
    .where('createdAt', '>=', Timestamp.fromDate(yesterday))
    .where('createdAt', '<=', Timestamp.fromDate(now))
    .get()
}
```

However, when I run this, I get the following error:

> error was 'FirebaseError: [code=invalid-argument]: Function Query.where() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: a custom Timestamp object'. Stacktrace was 'FirebaseError: Function Query.where() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: a custom Timestamp object

I am super confused, I have always fetched using Timestamp objects in other collections, and it does not work if I try to just use the date object. Have I forgotten something?

Edit: as requested, here is an example of what my doc looks like:

```
{
  name: "My Data Name", // (string)
  createdAt: November 9, 2018 at 8:40:45 PM // (Timestamp)
}
```

Comment: What does an example document record look like?

Comment: Your parentheses aren't matched up on the second where clause (the one with `now`).  Is that just a transcription error or is it really in the code?

Comment: Why check if the `createdAt` is less than or equal to `now` when you can leave it out? While it makes sense logically, data wouldn't exist beyond `now` and instead just wastes compute time (and your money).

Comment: @samthecodingman Adding a filters of any kind that does not also change the number of documents returned does not change the cost of the query.  The primary unit of billing in Cloud Firestore is number of documents read.  That is also the only metric of query performance.

Comment: @theJuls You should be able to pass either a Timestamp or Date object (which will be converted to a Timestamp).  Something else is very wrong if neither of those works.  What version of the SDK are you using?

Comment: @Kolban it is a simple document entry with essentially the name and `createdAt` timestamp. I've added it to the OP in case it helps with anything.

Comment: @robsiemb That was just an example simpler version of the code for this post. Will fix it though.

Comment: @samthecodingman I also use this for other timestamps that may be put in the future. This just so happens to be a case where I am passing in `now` which is also for an overly simple example.

Comment: @DougStevenson I am using `v7.0.0`. I remember not being able to use `Date` objects previously, but if I could, that would make my life easier, will check. Although I do want to know what could possibly be wrong that the Timestamps aren't working.

Comment: The latest is 7.2.3.  If that doesn't work, please file a bug report with Firebase support showing exactly what you're doing that reproduces the issue.  http://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. There are two things you need to check.

## 1. Am I using the right SDK?

Did you know there are two different firebase SDK you can use? One is a **client SDK** ([firebase-js-sdk](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/master/packages/firestore/src/api/timestamp.ts) a.k.a. `firebase` package) and the other one is a firebase **server SDK** ([nodejs-firestore](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-firestore/blob/master/dev/src/timestamp.ts) .a.k.a. `@google-cloud/firebase` package). These two libraries have its own implementation on `firestore.Timestamp` class and **THEY ARE NOT COMPATIBLE**.

Some of the other NPM packages dependencies as follow:

```
"@firebase/firestore" (*)
  -> "firebase" (client SDK which imports all @firebase/* except @firebase/testing)
    -> "@angular/fire" (and other client libraries with firebase binding)
    -> "@firebase/testing" (mocking Firestore client)

"@google-cloud/firebase" (*) (server SDK)
  -> "firebase-admin"
    -> "firebase-functions-test"
```

Where `(*)` denotes the location of `firestore.Timestamp` definition.

In short, you should use corresponding Timestamp.

#### Case 1. Use a client SDK only

```
import { firestore, initializeApp } from 'firebase';
import { config } from './my-firebase-config';

const app = initializeApp(config);
app.firestore().collection('users')
  .where('createdAt', '<=', firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date()))
  .get();
```

#### Case 2. Use a server SDK only

```
import { firestore, initializeApp } from 'firebase-admin';

const app = initializeApp();
app.firestore().collection('users')
  .where('createdAt', '<=', firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date()))
  .get();
```

#### Case 3. Mixing SDKs

Sometimes you need to use client SDK (specifically, `@firebase/testing`) when you're testing code that are run on server (e.g. firebase functions.)

```
// server.ts
import { firestore, initializeApp } from 'firebase-admin';

const app = initializeApp();
app.firestore().collection('users')
  .where('createdAt', '<=', fs.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date()))
  .get();
```

```
// server.test.ts
import { firestore } from 'firebase';
import { initializeAdminApp } from '@firebase/testing';

// Replace server sdk with client sdk
jest.mock('firebase-admin', () => ({
  firestore,
  initializeApp: () => initializeAdminApp()
}));
```

## 2. Am I using the right version?

If you're using the correct SDK, the next thing to check is whether you're using the same version of Timestamp implementation. If you're using Client SDK for example, then you should check your `package-lock.json` whether it has a unique version of `firebase`.

For my case, I installed `@firebase/testing` and `firebase` in a different time, and due to the difference `firebase` version dependency from `@firebase/testing`, I had two different `firebase` packages installed at the same time. You can update an old package to fix this.